# groovy dsl optional keyword

Tags: groovy, closures, dsl

I'm working on a DSL using groovy, and as i'm new to this language, i'm struggling on something.

i have this code

```
def from(state1) {
        def closure
        closure = { sensor ->
            [becomes: { signal ->
                // someProcess;
                [and:  closure]
            }]
        }
        [to: { state2 ->
            // someProcess
            [when: closure]
        }]
    };
```

what i do is to read this kind of sentances

```
from "on" to "off" when "button" becomes "high" and "button2" becomes "high"
```

the `and "button2" becomes "high"`, is optional. So grammatically, everything works as i wanted to.

the problem is that i wanted to add the possibility to treat `or` also, like this:

```
from "on" to "off" when "button" becomes "high" or "button2" becomes "high"
```

but i don't know how to do that. How can i do to add that, and also the possibility to know if it's `and` or `or` to have a control statement and a different process for each

it have been two days that i'm on the problem..

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

1st of all, I like your question!

Not knowing what your `//someProcess` is supposed to do and what the whole use-case is all about (IoT-ish?), you can implement the `or` operator like that:

```
...
    [to: { state2 ->
        [when: closure, whenEither:{ Map conds -> conds.any{ sensor, signal -> 'high' == signal } } ]
    }]
```

then you can write:

```
from "on" to "off" whenEither button:"high", button2:"high"
```